# Animated children's series where the 'baddies' were short and had Darth Vader-like helmets

Tags: story-identification, tv

This was on in the UK in the 80's on Saturday mornings. Specifically around 1984-5

Some more details:

I think there may have been three good characters - one of them a dog?

The baddies were white coloured like storm troopers except they all had Darth Vader shaped helmets and I think the lead baddie had black armour.

The animation style was possibly french, not particularly high budget, mostly flat 2D.

I can't remember much else except on one episode to get into the enemy base they knocked on the door and there was an exchange along the lines of:

> What do you want?
>
> To take over the base
>
> How many of you are there?
>
> **Two**
>
> That's not enough to take over the base I'm going come and check you out
>
> ....
>
> What do you want?
>
> To take over the base
>
> How many of you are there?
>
> **Three**
>
> That's not enough to take over the base I'm going come and check you out

...and so on until they had enough to take over the base.

Edit: Thanks to @HorusKol [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zx545107s9E&t=15m0s) is the exact scene I remembered

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! Can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and [edit] in anymore details you may remember.

Comment: That's a very evocative set of details.

Comment: I don't suppose you know if it was BBC or ITV?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [Robo Story](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robo_Story) (aka Myrtille and the Robots)

[Google Image search](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=robo+story&client=ms-android-htc&prmd=ivn&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&fir=W47fZoKBemJ9CM%253A%252CXukyPJXSFjDuNM%252C_%253BD9JHrRWA7cuxNM%253A%252CIa6arD4z_Z15rM%252C_%253B0mbWoX06YlsapM%253A%252CTMLxZjCRJUSpcM%252C_%253BVarMUB0YdknzqM%253A%252C4-LeqF_2yl2p4M%252C_%253BSy6bRRW22koelM%253A%252CZyThs4E7u5G9PM%252C_%253BpBExG1I70HYWRM%253A%252CNjIHi21VsnzvkM%252C_%253B5bK3JmjkRKd_1M%253A%252CDa1ym87Ad0bHsM%252C_%253BmjdMn1_iJR2tVM%253A%252C4VDTRUFvMfVDjM%252C_%253Bf_k4yvCmQkT00M%253A%252CqviceKycd__s4M%252C_%253BfaL2u5LtEGsInM%253A%252CzFr4tnwBtaL8TM%252C_&usg=__Kmlr33IGXOKDdTmuQ-L2aFDW3lc%3D&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4mfidl4nXAhWMHpQKHbPBBhQQ7AkIlgE&biw=360&bih=616#imgrc=_)

[image]

Comment: Yes! That’s the one. Brilliant.